# PostgreSQL: Trigger update

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have `t_a` and `t_b` tables, i need when there is a change in stats from `F` to `T` in the table `t_b`, the `stock` in `t_a` decreases from the `amount` in `t_b`.

t_a table

```
--------------
| id | stock |
--------------
| 1  | 20    |
| 2  | 40    |
--------------
```

t_b table

```
-----------------------
| id | amount | stats |
-----------------------
| 1  | 5      | F     |
| 2  | 7      | T     |
-----------------------
```

This is my query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_acc_a()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$DECLARE

BEGIN
 IF tg_op = 'UPDATE' THEN
  UPDATE public.t_a SET stock = stock-NEW.amount
  WHERE id = NEW.id; 
 END IF;
RETURN new;
END$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TRIGGER trg_acc_a
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON public.t_b
  FOR EACH ROW

  WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.fn_acc_a();
```

I want to add a condition when `stats = 'T'` on the trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its solved, I just adding if condition in function

```
IF tg_op = 'UPDATE' THEN 
    IF NEW.STATUS ='T' THEN
       UPDATE public.t_a SET stock = stock-NEW.amount
       WHERE id = NEW.id;
    END IF;
END IF;
```

Comment: You only need on `IF` statement `IF tg_op = 'UPDATE' AND new.status = 'T' THEN ...`